# AngularJS e2e Testing with Protractor and remote api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I would like to test my Angular app that is heavily dependent on an API. The API is being tested separately with phpunit and we are creating fixtures so ideally I was hoping to not have to create another set of mocked fixtures in Angular. I am using Protractor with the chrome driver only right now.

First I have to login through a page that is NOT an Angular app.

I then go to a page that shows a loader with `ng-if='loadingCards'` and hides a table with `ng-if='!loadingCards'` and then when the API call to retrieve cards is finished, the value of `loadingCards` is flipped.

Below is the beginning of the test spec which gets you through the non angular login and then takes you to the card listing page. All I would like to do is to see the contents of the `cards` $scope variable to see that the API has indeed returned something but I always get an empty array.

```
describe('User cards page', function() {
  var driver;
  var ptor;

  beforeEach(function() {
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    driver = ptor.driver;
  });

  it('should login', function() {
    driver.get('http://local.local.com/login');
    driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('_username')).sendKeys('admin');
    driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('_password')).sendKeys('admin');
    driver.findElement(protractor.By.css('input[type="submit"]')).click();
  });

  it('should list cards', function() {
    browser.get('http://local.local.com/cms/cards');

    var ucards = element.all(by.repeater('card in cards')).then(function(cards) {
        console.log(cards);
    });
    //expect(ucards.count()).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: What gives manual, visual checking ?

Comment: @davidb583 I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are mixing up two things. 
You can either write:

```
element.all(by.repeater('card in cards')).then(function(cards) {
    console.log(cards);
});
```

or:

```
var ucards = element.all(by.repeater('card in cards'));
ucards.then(function(cards) {
    console.log(cards);
});
```

but you are making kind of ... both.

Do you get any errors? Could you check for your current url?

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://local.local.com/cms/cards');
```

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for the response @nilsK. I dont think the way I am getting the promise on the repeater is incorrect, but you are right that I could write it slightly cleaner and easier to read. See my comment on Walters answer above. It was me adding an S to cards in the url which should have been card.

Comment: Ah, okay, great .... Really, this syntax worked? i was sure this threw an error in my tests .. mhh ;) greetings

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it() where the login takes place, follows the it() where you do the check of the card count. I would recommend moving the login part to the beforeEach.

And if that doesn't work, perhaps a ptor.sleep(300) could help. Place that just below the browser.get() of the page. The api may not have returned a value.

Comment: Thanks for the response Walter ... I tried both your suggestions to no avail. Just so you know for future, I didnt want to put the login in the beforeEach because once I had one login, I had a session and I didnt need to go back. And I tried the sleep but that didnt change anything either. ALTHOUGH, it did lead me to set the timeout to a minute, so I could look at the console and see I had used the wrong URL which I thought I was catching, but no. Thanks for pushing me down the right path!

Answer (score 0):

Walter helped me debug this by using the sleep command to keep the chromedriver iwndow open longer so I could see that the URL I was using was incorrect. One more test to create. Closing this.

Comment: I use the sleep command for this kind of debugging as well. Setting it to a minute, so you have a chance to look at the api calls that are being made. I still recommend doing the login in the beforeEach, because that is the proper place to do the necessary preparation for your tests. And detecting there if you already logged in, so the logging in happens only once. Anyway, glad I could help!

Comment: I am doing the login in another file that I ensure is run first in my protractor.conf file. It was really slowing it down logging in before each test. None the less, the debug technique has been priceless.

Comment: that sounds like even a better solution.